# Draggable element disappears in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Trying to create a draggable div, but instead of it dragging into the droppable div and snapping into it, the draggable div just disappears when dragged. As seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/45/) the div begins to disappear and still appends. I thought it might be a containment issue

```
$('.sorting').draggable({containment: 'parent', cursor:'pointer'});
```

When I changed the containment to parent from window the draggable div stays within as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/44/). Not understanding why the draggable div disappears and does not enter the droppable the box like I want. I am sure there is something I am not understanding or seeing that probably needs to be pointed out. I would also be very appreciative to know why this happens and any other tips one may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your draggable ul element disappears because of the overflow attribute of the .mousescroll class.

Replacing the css with

```
.mousescroll{
    float: left;
}
.mousescroll:hover {
}
```

fixes your problem.